# Why is the length of the array 3 when I have added 4 elements?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main() {
    int arr[] = {1,2,3};
    arr[3] = 4;
    printf("%d", sizeof(arr) / sizeof(1));  // To print the length of arr
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

I first created this array of length 3 and then at index 3 I put 4 as its value. So the length should be 4 now, but still, after compiling it is printing 3. Why?

Comment: Arrays can't change their lengths. Ever.

Comment: [Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2397984)

Comment: No you didn't change the length, instead `arr[3] = 4;` access the array one beyond the end of the array, which is undefined behavior.

Comment: Please compile you're code with warnings enabled, if using `gcc`/`clang`, consider at the least the options `-Wall -Werror -Wextra`.  Consider also, using [`valgrind`](https://valgrind.org/) to help diagnose runtime errors like this.

Comment: Unlike some other languages, C does not automatically resize arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is the length of the array 3 ...

Because you defined it like that here

```
int arr[] = {1,2,3};
```

Using `[]` and three initialisers, size 3, not going to change.

> ... when I have added 4 elements?

You did not add 4 elements, you created it with initially three elements, they were not added.

You did not even add a single element later.

In this code

```
arr[3] = 4;
```

you wrote a value to a memory location just behind the array. The array is not changed by that, especially not its size. Doing this causes Undefined Behaviour by the way.

C is like that, it allows you to do all kind of unwise things, without kindly telling you.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in C do not automatically extend themselves if you index outside the defined range.  When you write

```
arr[3] = 4;
```

you are writing *outside* the bounds of the array.

The problem is that C does not require any kinds of bounds checking on array accesses and places no requirement on the compiler or runtime environment to handle out-of-bounds indexing in any particular way - the behavior is *undefined*.  Any result is possible, including appearing to work as expected.  You could also overwrite another variable.  You could corrupt the stack frame leading to a crash later.

An array's size is fixed over its lifetime.  You can allocate space dynamically with `malloc` or `calloc` and resize it using the `realloc` function, but again that doesn't happen automatically, you have to write the code to keep track of the current size and resize as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create an array and then try to resize it. Arrays have a fixed size. If you want to store data dynamically, that is, with variable size, you need to use data structure.

Comment: It's still called "array", not "arrangement". Also, "static" has a specific meaning in the C language that is different from what you meant here. Be careful not to confuse these terms.

Comment: I am not completely conversant with the English language, I just use the translator. I understand that the terms were misused, my mistake.